# Using multiple lists with formulas

Tags: python, list

I have two input lists of floats:

```
   w = [3.11, 4.2, 5.66, 6]
   h = [1.1, 2.33, 3.222, 4.23]
```

I want to use them both in the same math formula where for each calculation it takes a value from the same index in the list:

```
   r = (h/2) + ((w^2) / (8*h))
```

so the formula would be as follows for the first pair of variables:

```
   r = (1.1/2) + ((3.11^2) / (8*1.1))
```

When done I want to create a list of results and append it to output variable `r`.

How would I go about this in Python? I know this is a rookie question but I cant figure this out.

Comment: Hint: `zip` is very useful problems like these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the builtin [`map`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) function, like this

```
w, h = [3.11, 4.2, 5.66, 6], [1.1, 2.33, 3.222, 4.23]

def formula(w, h):
    return (h/2.0) + ((w**2) / (8.0*h))

print map(formula, w, h)
# [1.6491022727272726, 2.1113519313304723, 2.853846058348852, 3.1788297872340427]
```

The same can be done with list comprehension and [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip), like this

```
print [(h/2.0) + ((w**2) / (8.0*h)) for w, h in zip(w, h)]
# [1.6491022727272726, 2.1113519313304723, 2.853846058348852, 3.1788297872340427]
```

Comment: Thank you this makes sense to me now. I also now understand the map() function. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Stackoverflow is more about fixing bugs than making code, but here goes it

```
def formulax(list1,list2):
  listOfOutputs = []
  i = 0
  while(i<=len(list1)) and i<=len(list2)):
    r = (list1[i]/2) + ((list2[i]^2) / (8*list1[i]))  
    listOfOutputs.append(r)
  return listOfOutputs
```